# How to extract a json request data in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

My LR response data for a API call has below details. I need to fetch each UPCs into a variable so that I can use it in my subsequent requests. How do I do this?

It is a json response data.

```
{
  "isRegistered": true,
  "points": 8383,
"Upcs": [
    "03546451",
    "03330067",
    "03332184",
    "03333822",
    "03334287",
    "06508814",
    "07433870",
    "06515393",
    "065153936666",
    "09836013",
    "09835870",
    "00081283 ",
    "01391343"
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using LR 12.53, you can use the latest JSON API to parse the JSON data.
For your case,

```
lr_eval_json("Buffer={JSON_INPUT}", "JsonObject=json_obj", LAST);
lr_json_get_values("JsonObject=json_obj", "ValueParam=upcs", "QueryString=$.Upcs", "SelectAll=Yes", LAST);
```

The upcs values will be stored in parameter upcs_1, upcs_2, ...

Comment: Hi Levi, thanks for your reply. I tried but this is not working. 



Action.c(42): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "vFullResponse" =  "{\n  "isRegistered" : true,\n  "pointsBalance" : 25,\n  "offerUpcs" : [ "03598030", "03598030" ],\n  "message" : "",\n  "tier" : "Base",\n  "stampCardBalances" : [ {\n    "type" : "00640398",\n    "amount" : 0\n  }, {\n    "type" : "03006399",\n    "amount" : 0\n  } ]\n}"
Action.c(42): lr_eval_json succeed
Action.c(45): Notify: Saving Parameter "offerUpcs_1 = ["03598030","03598030"]".

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done with web_reg_save_param_json function in LR 12.53.

```
web_reg_save_param_json(
    "ParamName=nameParam",
    "QueryString=$.Upcs.[*]",
    "SEARCH_FILTERS",
    "Scope=Body", "SelectAll=Yes",
    "LAST");
```

and the response is like this.

```
function.h(29): Notify: Saving Parameter "nameParam_1 = 00662772".    function.h(29): Notify: Saving Parameter "nameParam_2 = 00667488".    function.h(29): Notify: Saving Parameter "nameParam_3 = 00667489".    function.h(29): Notify: Saving Parameter "nameParam_4 = 00667490".    function.h(29): Notify: Saving Parameter "nameParam_5 = 21537499".    function.h(29): Notify: Saving Parameter "nameParam_6 = 06337500".    function.h(29): Notify: Saving Parameter "nameParam_7 = 06057501".    function.h(29): Notify: Saving Parameter "nameParam_8 = 02107502".    function.h(29): Notify: Saving Parameter "nameParam_9 = 21537503".    function.h(29): Notify: Saving Parameter "nameParam_10 = 06017504".    function.h(29): Notify: Saving Parameter "nameParam_11 = 02117505".    function.h(29): Notify: Saving Parameter "nameParam_12 = 06017506".    function.h(29): Notify: Saving Parameter "nameParam_13 = 01097507".    function.h(29): Notify: Saving Parameter "nameParam_14 = 01137508".    function.h(29): Notify: Saving Parameter "nameParam_count = 14".
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving Multiple Matches

The `web_reg_save_param_json` function supports array type parameters. When you specify `SelectAll=Yes`, all the occurrences of the match are saved in an array. Each element of the array is represented by the `ParamName_index`. In the following example, the parameter name is A:

```
web_reg_save_param_json("ParamName= A", "QueryString=$..arguments.additional_context[0].name", "SelectAll=Yes", LAST );
```

The first match is saved as A_1, the second match is saved as A_2, and so forth. You can retrieve the total number of matches by using the following term: `ParamName_count`. For example, to retrieve the total number of matches saved to the parameter array, use:

```
TotalNumberOfMatches=atoi(lr_eval_string("{A_count}"));
```

More details refer: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/vugen/en/2022-2022-r2/help/function_reference/Content/FuncRef/web/lrFr_web_reg_save_param_json.htm?cshid=web_reg_save_param_json#Saving_Multiple_Matches