# How to store multiple parameters from a same URL in Loadrunner using "web_reg_save_param_json"

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I am new to LR, I have a URL which returns JSON in the below structure

```
{
  "Indo-European": {
    "Indo-Iranian": {
      "Iranian": [
        "Persian"
      ],
      "Indic": [
        "Assamese",
        "Bengali"
      ]
    },
    "Baltic": [
      "Latvian",
      "Lithuanian"
    ],
    "Slavic": {
      "East Slavic": [
        "Russian"
      ],
      "South Slavic": [
        "Bulgarian"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to call the URL **[www.blahblah.com/culture/languages](http://www.blahblah.com/culture/languages)** only **once** and want multiple values(Persian, Russian, Bulgarian) stored in different parameters(Lang1,lang2,bloo3).

Currently the approach for a single param is

```
web_reg_save_param_json(
    "ParamName=c_JSONValue",
    "QueryString=$.Indo-European.Indo-Iranian.Indic[1]",
    "NotFound=warning",
    "SelectAll=Yes",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "Scope=BODY",
    "IgnoreRedirections=Yes",
    "RelFrameID=1",
    "RequestUrl=http://demoptsite.com",
    LAST);
```

Updating the Question to have more clarity
Is there any other better way to capture multiple values with different query string parameter and parameter name in short I would want to load the url once and capture multiple different params , please help me out here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237031/how-to-extract-a-json-request-data-in-loadrunner

Comment: Meaning split this function to to or more functions. One to load Jason response and more to query it.

Comment: But the link you have shared all have same Query string pattern which is not the case for me, I would want to use different query string pattern, Could you pls elaborate on how exactly are you suggesting the split?

Comment: https://perfgenx.blogspot.com/2018/01/how-to-handle-json-request-in.html?m=1